# How to change the object view in paper_trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, paper-trail-gem

I have used paper_trail gem for auditing in the application i am developing. I am able to manage most of its features and i was able to display the data in versions table to the user. In doing so the data in object attribute of the versions table is some what unreadable. How can i make it be readable?
Here is my sample output of the object attribute:
`version.object` retrieves in the following format in a single cell:

```
--- budget_year: '2014' name: bbb reference_number: j789789 requesting_unit: '798789' quarter: II source_of_fund: Government budget_type: Recurrent procurement_method: Open Bidding procurement_level: National estimated_cost: 4455.0 currency: '4545' purchase_request_id: start_at: 2014-07-30 end_at: 2014-07-31 created_at: 2014-07-24 08:29:38.000000000 Z updated_at: 2014-07-24 08:29:38.000000000 Z id: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reify` method to see your data like,

```
   > i=Invoice.last.versions.last

   => <PaperTrail::Version id: 158, item_type: "Invoice", item_id: 115, event: "update", whodunnit: "3", object: "---\nid: 115\ncreated_at: 2015-02-05 06:43:17.278448..."> 
 :038 > i.object
   => "---\nid: 115\ncreated_at: 2015-02-05 06:43:17.278448000 Z\nupdated_at: 2015-02-05 06:43:17.278448000 Z\nentity_type: Site\nentity_id: 928\ninvoice_id: WS/14\nuser_id: \nperson_id: \nstatus: 0\nperson_email:\nentity_value:\naddress: ''\nprice: '666'\ndetails: '{\"domain\"=>\"\", \"package\"=>\"23\", \"site_id\"=>\"928\", \"user_id\"=>\"394\", \"years\"=>\"1\"}'\norder_id: '464'\nnorder_type: \nyear: 1\npayment_type: cash\naccount_type: \ncheque_name: ''\ncomment: \ntax: \ncomments: 'Customer made payment by cash with receipt Nos: 041 & 042.'\ncheque_number: \nchequenumber: ''\npayment_level: \ninvoice_type: \n"

  > i.reify
  => <Invoice id: 115, created_at: "2015-02-05 06:43:17", updated_at: "2015-02-05 06:43:17", entity_type: "Site", entity_id: 928, invoice_id: "WS/14-15/D-2119", user_id: nil, person_id: nil, status: 0, address: "Near So...", price: "4999", details: "{\"domain\"=>\"\", \"package\"=>\"23\", \"site_id\"=>\"928\", ...", order_id: "464", order_type: nil, year: 1, payment_type: "cash", account_type: nil, cheque_name: "", comment: nil, tax: nil,, cheque_number: nil, chequenumber: "", payment_level: nil, invoice_type: nil>
```

or

```
> PaperTrail.serializer.load(i.object)
=> {"id"=>115, "created_at"=>2015-02-05 06:43:17 UTC, "updated_at"=>2015-02-05 06:43:17 UTC, "entity_type"=>"Site", "entity_id"=>928, "invoice_id"=>"W", "user_id"=>nil, "person_id"=>nil, "status"=>0, "person_email"=>"rium@gmail.com", "entity_value"=>"u.com", "address"=>"li ", "price"=>"4999", "details"=>"{}", "orr_id"=>"655", "processed_by"=>"", "order_type"=>nil, "year"=>1, "payment_type"=>"cash", "account_type"=>nil, "cheque_name"=>"", "comment"=>nil, "tax"=>nil, "comments"=>"Customer made payment by cash with receipt Nos: 041 & 042.", "cheque_number"=>nil, "chequenumber"=>"", "payment_level"=>nil, "invoice_type"=>nil}
```

second way will give the form of `hash`.